# How do I initialize elements of an array, 1 through 10, and then use that constructor in a method that will print the elements?

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I have an assignment for object-oriented programming class. I've been trying to take the values of an array that were initialized in a constructor, and use the values from that constructor to print them in a different method called `printArrayValues`. I cannot seem to 'call' or return the values in the method.. I've been troubleshooting for hours and I'm getting frustrated.

The assignment's steps are as follows:

- The constructor for the `ExerciseOne` class initializes and instantiates `myArray` as an array of ten integers, and initializes the elements of the array with the values `1` through `10`, using a for-loop.

  - You must assign the values in terms of the for-loop index variable, for example, `i`.
- The class has a method called `printArrayValues` that uses a for-loop and `System.out.print()` statement to print out the values of the elements of the array, as shown in the sample output.

  - This method has no parameters, and no return value.

I've tried creating a new variable in the constructor, and then calling it in the method, but it's not working.

```
public class ExerciseOne {

    public int[] myArray;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExerciseOne aExerciseOne = new ExerciseOne();
        aExerciseOne.printArrayValues();

    }

    ExerciseOne() {
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            this.myArray = new int[i];
        }

    }

    public void printArrayValues() {
        System.out.print("myArray = {");
        for (int a = 0; a < myArray.length; a++) {
        System.out.print((myArray[a] + 1));
        if (a < 9) {
            System.out.print(",");
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("};");
        }

        }

    }
    //
    //public void displayArrayProduct() {
    //  for (int  : myArray) {
    //      
    //  }
    //  
    //}

}
```

I got frustrated and just created the loop, to initialize it, in the method. This is incorrect for the assignment, but I wanted to move on. Honestly I'm very lost at this point and I'm sorry if that makes it more difficult to help me.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `for` loop. `myArray = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 , 10};` should have already done that work for you.

Comment: sorry, that was me experimenting, and I forgot I did that. I've deleted it. The assignment wants a for loop to initialize the array, and it want's the array to be instantiated and initialized inside the constructor. How would I obtain the values from the constructor, and display them in another method?

Comment: You are using `myArray.length` but you don't seem to know why you are using it. What value do you expect `myArray.length` to have?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code.

```
public class ExerciseOne {

public int[] myArray = new int[10];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExerciseOne aExerciseOne = new ExerciseOne();
    aExerciseOne.printArrayValues();
}

ExerciseOne() {
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        this.myArray[i] = i+1;
    }
}

public void printArrayValues() {
    System.out.print("myArray = {");
    for (int a = 0; a < myArray.length; a++) {
        System.out.print((myArray[a]));
        if (a < 9) {
            System.out.print(",");
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("};");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Output: myArray = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

Comment: You have to initialize your global array like this  public int[] myArray = new int[10];

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the same array twice. Your program will work the same if you use any of below :

```
myArray = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 , 10};
```

or

```
myArray = new int[10]; for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) { this.myArray[i]=i+1; }
```

as your array is not 2d array so you cant assign another array on elements of array.

```
this.myArray = new int[i]; // not correct
```

Comment: Thank you. How would I take the values of the elements of the array, and display them in another method now?

Comment: As the myArray is global variable so it will be visible to all the methods and once you have initialized it inside the constructor. Those values will be available in another method too. Only thing is you wont have to do 
        System.out.print((myArray[a] + 1));
You can use
        System.out.print((myArray[a]));

Answer (score 0):

I've written and tested the below and it returns the output you need.  Please note that it's been written in C# for a console application. If it helps then please remember to vote for me.

Create your ExerciseOne class like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test
{
    public class ExerciseOne
    {
        int[] eo;
        public ExerciseOne()
        {
            eo = new int[10];

            for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
            {
                eo[i] = i + 1;
            }
            printArrayValues();
        }

        public void printArrayValues()
        {
            foreach (var item in eo)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Then call the class like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExerciseOne one = new ExerciseOne();
        }
    }
}
```